# How to fill IEnumerable<T> after HttpPost request mvc 3?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i want to make a form using below code i developed Model for View :

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Comment: Are you sure that `AssembliesOperation.GetClasses(path, typeof(JobBase))` actually returns anything?

Comment: What part of the program is displayed on the screenshot with debug? It does not look like any of code snippets above.

Comment: Danile: i am sure also IsNotDefined and IsDefined is null.

Comment: Andrei: i added your request. Thanks...

Comment: And you are sure that `item.ClassName == className` ever evaluates to true? Have you debugged to make sure the PList is actually populated and is not reset on the way out?  Also, isnotdefined/isdefined is not set in your example code, so the should be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the following blog post to better understand how the model binding works for collections and how your input fields should be named: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

OK, now let's get rid of this `foreach` loop and use editor templates, shall we?

```
<table style="width:65%; vertical-align:top" id="sample">
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Properties) %>
</table>
```

and now define an editor template that will automatically be rendered for each element of the properties collection (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/PropertyModel.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<PropertyModel>" 
%>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.ParameterName) %>
    </td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ParameterName) %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As far as those radio buttons are concerned, there's something wrong in your design about them. They are not part of the collection model but part of the main view model and yet you are putting them inside the foreach loop that is rendered for each element of the collection property. You might need to rethink what you are trying to do here.